# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Win Auth main site, but sub-folder as anonymous

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis-7

I want to have a sub-folder that allows anonymous users to download files on an ASP.NET Core site that is secured using Window Authentication.  I have static files enabled on wwwroot (as in app.UseStaticFiles), but I don't see how to make the sub-folder use anonymous security.  I tried using a web.config in the sub-folder with  but that didn't work.  I don't recall this being as difficult when not using Core, any help appreciated.

Comment: You have to make a sub application in IIS with it's own security settings. The alternative is allowing both in your base app and adding [Authorize] to your restricted controllers.

Comment: That's a good idea, I tried it as a standard ASP.NET and it still required the Windows Auth.  I put the folder under 'wwwroot' as an Anon app.  I think the ASP.NET Core is still pushing the Win Auth and not recognizing the sub app.  Also, how would you secure other static files/folders that are not Controller managed if I go the [Authorize] way?

Comment: @Tratcher If you want credit for the answer you can post your comment below and I'll mark it even though I just posted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some extra research, here's the solution I arrived at.

Like @Tratcher suggested, I enabled Anonymous along side Windows Auth in IIS.

I referenced the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication and added it in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddAuthentication(
      Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Added a default authorization policy when adding MVC:

```
services.AddMvc(o =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

The default policy means I didn't have to use the Authorize attribute everywhere.
But with this solution it opened up the "wwwroot" static files, so I needed a place to secure some files.

To secure some sub-folders I used this [middleware solution by Scott Allen](https://web.archive.org/web/20210729025712/https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/10/06/authorization-policies-and-middleware-in-asp-net-5.aspx) that scans requested paths and authorizes them by policy.